# How to store only metadata of local & cloud storage files in SharePoint Online, not the files themselves?

Tags: sharepoint, google-drive-api, office365, sharepoint-online, cloud-storage

I am new to SharePoint Online, but haven't found anything via Google: I have tons of files (read: terabytes) stored on my filesystem and on a cloud storage and want to access their metadata to allow searching for them. Is this possible without uploading them into SharePoint Online? It should also be possible to "sync" the hierarchy of the crawled folder so I can click through the folder structure in SharePoint. I do not want to store the content of these files though (for storage space reasons).

It is like having a synced folder in SharePoint where the files are searchable, but they are just shortcuts of some kind, without content.

I thought of creating some sort of timed job which crawls the file system and creates empty files in SharePoint which contain the metadata and a link to the file, but this seems very crude to me. Is there a better solution or maybe even something SharePoint Online itself provides?

// edited: I need to crawl not only files on my filesystem but also cloud storage files of different cloud storage services.
// whoops got that wrong, it is SharePoint Online, not 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file share as one of the sources. SharePoint will be able to crawl & Index the files in the file share.

Steps on how to do it can be found here...
     [How to: Configure Enterprise Search to index a file share](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/07/01/how-to-configure-enterprise-search-to-index-a-file-share.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works perfect for local files & shares! Unfortunately this does not allow to browse the folder structure in SharePoint, and it is only working for cloud storages which I have synced locally - I updated my question accordingly.